# Please tell me why the c code behaves this way in detail?

Tags: c, gcc

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    unsigned x = 1;
    signed char y = -1;

    if(x>y) printf("x>y");
    else printf("x<=y");

}
```

The output of the code when compiled on gcc is   `"x<=y"`

Please explain anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `x>y`, we have an `unsigned` and a `signed char`. The rules of C say that the types are made to match by converting the `signed char` to an `unsigned` value, and then the comparison is performed.

When −1 is converted to `unsigned`, the result cannot be −1, of course, because `unsigned` cannot represent negative values. The rules of C say that a conversion of a negative value to `unsigned` is performed by adding `UINT_MAX+1` to the value (as many times as necessary to make a non-negative value). For example, if `UINT_MAX` is 65535, then 65536 is added. So the result of converting −1 to `unsigned` is −1 + 65536 = 65535.

Thus, the comparison becomes `1>65535`, which is false. (`UINT_MAX` can also be larger, such as 4,294,967,295, in which case the comparison becomes `1>4294967295`, which is also false.)

Comment: I would add that you should be explicit about the type of unsigned (unsigned char, unsigned int, unsigned short, unsigned long). Also, you should really only do arithmetic between the same type, or if that is not practical, cast to make the conversion explicit: for example, average= (double)x/(double)y;